# host PDF on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to host a PDF on S3 and be able to share a link to it to anyone. I've seen this done before, but cannot figure it out.

So far I've uploaded the PDF to a bucket which works. Then when I click on it, go to "Properties" and press "Open", it works. Giving me a url such as `https://my-file.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my%20file.pdf?lotsofqueries`, which I'm able to access from anywhere.

The issue is, this link seems to expire after an hour or so.

Comment: Do you only want to make this one file 'public', or would you like to make the whole bucket (or part of the bucket) public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the object **permanently** public you have to do two things:

1. Disable [Blocking public access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) to your bucket.
2. Setup [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/bucket-policies.html) allowing for anonymous access to the object, e.g.:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket>/<name-of-the-file>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If you just want to make it public for **few hours** only, then you can generated a [presigned URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to the file.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a separate "public files" bucket if you are going to disable public blocking.   That way you won't accidentally share something you don't mean to.  If you create a bucket policy then restrict it to a specific folder or file not the whole bucket.

Comment: @Marcin done that, where can I grab the sharable url from? And would like this to be permanent